# http://www.inc.com/ drop menu effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to achieve drop and hide menu effect from http://www.inc.com/

this is my current fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/elementhttp/56ThC/

```
    $("#1").mouseover(function(){  
    //alert("aaaaaaaaaa"); just for testing
    $(".block2").stop().fadeToggle(700);
     });
 $("#1").mouseout(function(){      
    $(".block2").stop().fadeToggle(700);
     });

$(".menu2").mouseover(function(){  
    //alert("aaaaaaaaaa"); 
    $(".con2").stop().fadeToggle(700);
     });
$(".menu2").mouseout(function(){      
    $(".con2").stop().fadeToggle(700);
     });
```

currently when you hover over menu 1 item fade occurs but it doesn't stay showed

thanks for your help in solving this mystery :D

Comment: why negative ratings? Just give my a hints for improvement not a whole code

Comment: Please specify the effect you want to achieve with actual words in your question instead of a link to `inc.com`, whatever it might be. Please also elaborate on what exactly is not working with your current code.

Comment: Drop and show / hide menu effect code is not working because i need help in achieving that effect .When you mouse over menu it drops down and shows content i need it to stay not to hide immediately

Comment: Removing the `.mouseout` sections of code will make the area stay visible, but then what determines when it hides again?

Comment: Dryden Long  thats a question ! ty

Comment: @Ivan Yes, it is a question... The reason I asked is because I, and I'm sure others, need some clarification on what it is you are trying to accomplish. Asking questions helps us better determine how to help you, unless you don't answer them, of course.

Comment: I am apologizing for my lack of explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your submenus are not childs of the top menu, the 'mouseout' event is being called every time you move the mouse out of the menu.

I fixed your HTML, Javascript and CSS and cleaned some code to give you examples (http://jsfiddle.net/56ThC/1/).

```
<body>
<div class="block">
    <div class="box" id="1">
        menu1
        <div class="submenu" id="1">
            <div class="box2">item1_1</div>
            <div class="box2">item1_2</div>
            <div class="box2">item1_3</div>
            <div class="box2">item1_4</div>
            <div class="box2">item1_5</div>
         </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="box " id="2">
        menu2
        <div class="submenu" id="2">
            <div class="box2">item2_1</div>
            <div class="box2">item2_2</div>
            <div class="box2">item2_3</div>
            <div class="box2">item2_4</div>
            <div class="box2">item2_5</div>
         </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="3">
        menu3
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="4">
        menu4
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="5">
        menu5
    </div>

 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.submenu').hide();


$(".box").hover(function(){  
    $(this).find(".submenu").stop().fadeToggle(700);
});
```

CSS:

```
.block{
    width: 615px;
    border: solid 1px #aaa;  
    text-align: center;  
    white-space: nowrap;  
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box{
    width: 100px;  
    height: 50px;  
    border: solid 1px #ccc;  
    display: inline-block;  
    vertical-align: middle;         
}   
.submenu{
    width: 615px;
    height:300px; 
    position:absolute;left:8px;top:60px;
    border: solid 1px #aaa;  
    text-align: center;  
    white-space: nowrap;  
    overflow: hidden;
            }
.box2{
    width: 200px;  
    height: 200px;  
    border: solid 1px #ccc;  
    display: inline-block;  
    vertical-align: middle;         
           }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thats a way to go thank you Yani!

Comment: Hi Yani how to align this to be at center of the screen effect , when i try to align center or margin auto effect submenu is dislocated